# Convert a sequential conditions script into a general process

Tags: python, oop, hashmap

I'm currently working on generalizing a sequential pipeline with many conditions;
lets say I have a fruit data, describing apples, bananas and pears and their corresponding weight & color.

```
import pandas as pd
fruits = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Pear' 'Pear', 'Banana'],
                      'Weight': [42, 64, 82, 74, 51, 71],
                      'Color': ['Red', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Green' 'Red', 'Yellow']})
```

I want to use all or partial features to classify the fruits into groups of 'Red_big_apples', 'Green_big_apples', 'Red_small_apples', 'Green_small_apples', 'Red_big_pears'.. etc.

```
for i in list(fruits.index):
    if fruits.loc[i, 'Fruit'] == 'Apple':
        if fruits.loc[i, 'Weight'] < 50:
            if fruits.loc[i, 'Color'] == 'Red':
                fruits.loc[i, 'Group'] = 'Red_small_apples'
ect.
```

Now imagine that I have a much more complex sequential conditional pipeline and a completely new and different complex sequential conditional pipeline may be needed to be implemented in a few weeks.

The main idea was to create a combinatorial df/hashmap  that will communicate with a certain function in a class (I'll create) to extract the final group of the given fruit -
but as I build the df/hashmap (a complex mission on its own) I understand how big it's gonna be (~2000 rows/combinations).

My question is, what do think is the best way to approach this issue?

In case of inner changes or a new pipeline, which way the grouping will be:

1. The fastest computationally
2. Easiest to implement

Which way will be the most generalized so I wouldn't need to change the class and/or class function in such cases?

1. df/hashmap
2. specific function
3. other

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing can be achieved using apply like so:

```
def classify(x):
    if x.Weight > 50:
        return f"{x.Color}_big_{x.Fruit}"
    else:
        return f"{x.Color}_small_{x.Fruit}"

fruits['class'] = fruits.apply(classify, axis=1)
```

This generates:

```
Fruit   Weight  Color   class
0   Apple   42  Red Red_small_Apple
1   Apple   64  Green   Green_big_Apple
2   Banana  82  Yellow  Yellow_big_Banana
3   Pear    74  Green   Green_big_Pear
4   Pear    51  Red Red_big_Pear
5   Banana  71  Yellow  Yellow_big_Banana
```

A more complicated condition can further be realized by modifying your `classify` function.

Comment: I know the example I gave is pretty simple, but imagine a complex pipeline, with much more steps, classifications and inner-dependencies, while there are different conditions to different classes.

Comment: Is it possible to generate these rules programmatically? If not you will have to enumerate these rules ones.